# Fetch user info after logging in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I made a page that shows the users, but it shows all the users, I wanted to only show the user that has logged in how am I gonna do that? here is my code.

Code:

```
<form method="post" action="edit2.php">
<table>
<tr><td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="contactno"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"</td></tr>

</table>
</form> 
<table border='1'>
<?PHP
$customerquery=mysql_query("select * from customerinfo");
while($customerrows=mysql_fetch_array($customerquery)){
?>

<tr>
<td>Id</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Address</td><td>Contact No</td <td>Username</td><td>Password</td><td>Edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['id'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['fname'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['lname'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['address'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['contactno'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['username'];?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $customerrows['password'];?></td>
<td><a href="edit2.php<?PHP echo '?id='.$customerrows['id']; ?>">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<a href="login1.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this code is showing all the users, you have a broken `update` somewhere that set all the `username` fields to the same value... actually there's not even a loop around this output. Something's not kosher here.

Comment: If you want to list all logged-in users. You'l have to maintain first list of all logged-in user in separate table (or use a `status` column to represent logged-in status and based on that just compare `status` field and show.

Comment: i edited my code i forgot to post my original code sorry

Comment: what do you mean status sir? sorry im just new in php

Comment: @JasonC: He aded new code while I was editing, sorry.

Comment: @Dinistro sorry i edited my code because as I stated in the problem the users are all shown so I added the while loop in the code, sorry